# Multitasking Vim on Windows

Tags: windows, vim

On Linux you press Control Z to jump back to the shell, so the question is on Windows how do you do that?

I've tried Control Z, Control D, and being on a laptop I'm missing the Pause/Break key.

Currently I'm using ConEmu for Multitasking.

Comment: Are you open to the possibility to use gvim and just alt tab to a terminal window?

Comment: When I run the vim.exe I built in a cmd.exe terminal, and press CTRL-Z, I get a terminal window back. When I exit that terminal I get Vim back. What happens when you press CTRL-Z? Do you have any mappings for CTRL-Z on Windows?